# React native unrecognized font family using external Svg

Tags: react-native, svg

I'm implementing a react native app (with expo, I don't know if this can be relevant). In this app I'm sending an ajax request to an external service and that service returns a list of URLs related to images in svg format that I need to show in my app.

To show the images I'm using [react-native-svg](https://github.com/react-native-svg/react-native-svg) library (I've tried with `Svg/Image` and with `SvgUri`). Generally it work properly, but there is some SVG that break my app, because it includes a font-family not supported by my react-native project and the iOS simulator is showing me the error: `Unrecognized font family '<FONT-FAMILY-NAME>'`.

I've already checked several post on stackoverflow and they all suggest to add the specific font-family to the project, but this solution will not fix my issue in log term as in future I can receive a new SVG file with a different font that will break again my app. I obviously have absolutely no control on the SVG provided by the external service. So, what I'm interested to know is:

1. Is there any way to add *dynamically* a font-family to react-native project? For dynamically I mean that the app will add the font to its list when it's required by the SVG file
2. By using `Svg`/`Image` (or with `SvgUri`) is there any way I can overwrite the font to avoid it to break the app?

Thanks in advance for your answers.

Comment: Have you found a solution for this? I'm getting the same, remote SVG has some fonts not present in the app and fallback for fonts is not working...

Comment: Sorry @Symyon, but I haven't found a solution yet.